# there is not StringBuffer in class file

Tags: java

```
  public class Alog
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String str = new B() + null;

    System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

please tell me why,some said that new Stringbuffer().append(new B().toString()).append(null);so where is that
thanks very much

Comment: what output would you want to have?

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Comment: the code will be replaced by StringBuilder in jvm only when running,because i did not see any change between class and java file;